# How debug a Yii2 migration?

Tags: yii2, migration

I'm a looking for a way for see a preview before execute a migration, something like debug an Active Record but into a migration.

```
// Example for debug sql for a Active record
echo $query->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

My purpose is save time in the trial and error process.

I would like know if exists a way for debug sql query before run.

Comment: preview of what ? You want sql of activeRecord and query ?

Comment: Hi, please give more info and provide source code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ttrasn I want sql of migration before run, because sometimes if I made a mistake I have to delete manually the errors into database and try again. I would like know if exist a way for debug sql before run.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot debug migration. Just run the migration and see what happens.